# Laravel: How to access raw input during create and update, from a trait?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, traits

I am writing a Trait for Laravel eloquent models that enables "promotion" of input elements during create and update. The base trait looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait PromotesInputsDuringCreation {

    public static function doPromotion($attrs) {
        if (isset(static::$promotions) && !empty(static::$promotions)){
            foreach (static::$promotions as $target => $path) {
                $pathParts = explode('.', $path);
                $targetData = $attrs;
                foreach ($pathParts as $part){
                    if (is_null($targetData)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    $targetData = is_object($targetData) ? $targetData->$part : $targetData[$part];
                }
                if(!is_null($targetData)) {
                    $attrs[$target] = $targetData;
                }
            }
        }
        return $attrs;
    }
```

The models that implement the trait would define a `$promotions` array that looks something like this:

```
public static $promotions = [
    'loan_status_end_date' => 'loan_status.end_date',
    'loan_status_type' => 'loan_status.type'
];
```

The goal of this trait is to accept inputs with nested arrays/objects full of data, and to selectively promote *some* of that data to new top-level keys. This enables easier sorting/searching at the database level once it is saved.

The issue I am having is that no solution I have tried "does it all"

First solution: The boot method

Problem: Boot method callbacks receive an already instantiated model which does not contain the raw data passed into ::create() / ::updateOrCreate() / similar methods. (Or, if it does, I am not aware how to access it. Please let me know if I am dumb)

Example Code:

```
    public static function bootPromotesInputsDuringCreation()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
//$model->getDirty() only gets attributes that exactly match data keys
            $model->attributes = array_intersect_key(self::doPromotion($model->getDirty()), $model->attributes);
        });
        static::updating(function ($model) {
//$model->getDirty() only gets attributes that will change in the update
            $model->attributes = array_intersect_key(self::doPromotion($model->getDirty()), $model->attributes);
        });
    }
```

Second solution: Overriding creation methods

Problem: The promotion works, but the following creation method skips model casting and other laravel niceties I rely on. All attempts to use `static::create()` or `parent::create()` with the promoted data create infinite loops.

Example Code:

```
    public static function create($data) 
    {
        return (new static)->newQuery()->create(self::doPromotion($data));
    }

    public static function updateOrCreate($where, $data)
    {
        $data = self::doPromotion($data);

        if ((new static)->newQuery()->where($where)->exists()) {
            // this skips $casts and other model events :(
            return (new static)->newQuery()->where($where)->update($data);
        }

        return (new static)->newQuery()->create([...$where, ...$data]);
    }
```

It really feels like I am inches away from making this trait work. Anyone see what I am missing? Could be as simple as finding a way to get the raw creation/update input inside the boot method or calling create/update in the overridden methods in a different way that invokes those laravel niceties.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should use Observer and Cast instead of Trait.

Comment: while creating isn't the whole model "dirty"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to override the `fill()` method found in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` with an exact copy on my trait that simply adds the call to `doPromotions()` before continuing its usual processing.

Id like this to be cleaner and more resilient to changes in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` over time, but for now this works well. Please comment any improvements in readability or elegance. The code is below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException;

trait PromotesInputsDuringCreation {

    public static function doPromotion($attrs) {
        if (isset(static::$promotions) && !empty(static::$promotions)){
            foreach (static::$promotions as $target => $path) {
                $pathParts = explode('.', $path);
                $targetData = $attrs;
                $success = true; 
                //re-checking arbitrary states at the end can be ambiguous, $success makes it explicit.
                foreach ($pathParts as $part){
                    if (is_null($targetData)) {
                        $success = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((is_object($targetData) && !isset($targetData->$part)) 
                        || (!is_object($targetData) && !isset($targetData[$part]))){
                            $success = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    $targetData = is_object($targetData) ? $targetData->$part : $targetData[$part];
                }
                if($success) {
                    $attrs[$target] = $targetData;
                }
            }
        }
        return $attrs;
    }

    /**
     * Fill the model with an array of attributes.
     * 
     * This is an identical copy of the same method 
     * from Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, with the
     * addition of the first call to doPromotion() that
     * this trait enables
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return $this
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException
     */
    public function fill(array $attributes)
    {
        $attributes = self::doPromotion($attributes);

        $totallyGuarded = $this->totallyGuarded();

        $fillable = $this->fillableFromArray($attributes);

        foreach ($fillable as $key => $value) {
            // The developers may choose to place some attributes in the "fillable" array
            // which means only those attributes may be set through mass assignment to
            // the model, and all others will just get ignored for security reasons.
            if ($this->isFillable($key)) {
                $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
            } elseif ($totallyGuarded || static::preventsSilentlyDiscardingAttributes()) {
                if (isset(static::$discardedAttributeViolationCallback)) {
                    call_user_func(static::$discardedAttributeViolationCallback, $this, [$key]);
                } else {
                    throw new MassAssignmentException(sprintf(
                        'Add [%s] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [%s].',
                        $key, get_class($this)
                    ));
                }
            }
        }

        if (count($attributes) !== count($fillable) &&
            static::preventsSilentlyDiscardingAttributes()) {
            $keys = array_diff(array_keys($attributes), array_keys($fillable));

            if (isset(static::$discardedAttributeViolationCallback)) {
                call_user_func(static::$discardedAttributeViolationCallback, $this, $keys);
            } else {
                throw new MassAssignmentException(sprintf(
                    'Add fillable property [%s] to allow mass assignment on [%s].',
                    implode(', ', $keys),
                    get_class($this)
                ));
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a global observer is better for this

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait PromotesInputsDuringCreation {

    public static function doPromotion($attrs) {...};
    
    public static function bootPromotesInputsDuringCreation()         
    {          
         static::observe(app(PromotesInputsObserver::class));    
    }
}
```

than you can create this `PromotesInputsObserver` and implement your `creating` and `updating` events. But since `getDirty` is looking for dirty attributes and your `loan_status` is not a property of your model, it will not show up as a dirty attribute. Your `loan_status` is never being compared.

```php
class PromotesInputsObserver
{
    public function creating(Model $model)
    {
        $model::doPromotion($model->only($model::$promotions));
        
        foreach($model::$promotions => $target) {
            unset($model->$target);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

also rather that defining `promotions` as a static property of the model and than checking if that property exists, it's easier to define it as a method `public function promotions(): array` and implement it on your trait as `return [];`. Than each model can overwrite this method with it's own array but you don't need to worry if that function exists on the model or not.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think this addresses the core issue. Even the observer pattern does not get access to the mass assignment input array. `loan_status` doesnt exist on the model, so it cant be accessed to be promoted in the observer, even during `creating` and `updating` methods.

Is there no way to access the creation process with that information intact?

Comment: @ChkltLabs you have to set `load_status` on the model at some point, otherwise why handle this on the events? Even tho `load_status` is not stored in the DB I assume you pass it to the model on your controller, no?